# How to solve: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I have been searching the internet to find out what exactly is the problem with my code. When I login with email and password the auth state changes and my users are taken to the home screen but, when I use the google login button it says: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

However, the user is also created in the firebase console. Please what is the reason?

Below is the code in routes.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, DarkTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {View} from 'react-native'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthProvider';
import AStack from '../Pages/AuthStack.js';
import Navigation from '../Navigation.js';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import {AdmobController} from '../Componets/AdmobController';
 
const Routes = () => {

  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if(initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide()
  }, [])

  if(initializing) return null

    return (
     
      <NavigationContainer>
       <AdmobController>
          { user ?  <Navigation />  : <AStack />}
          </AdmobController>
      </NavigationContainer>
    
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

Below is my code in the Auth provider:

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, View, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import { Segment, Spinner} from "native-base";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          
        Alert.alert(
            e.message);
          }
        },
        register: async (name, email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, name);
            firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
            firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName: name
    });
            Alert.alert("Account Created Successfully ✅", "Kindly check your email and verify your membership in three")
            return {};
          }
          catch (error) {
           
            if (error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
              Alert.alert('This email is already in use! Kindly try another email')
            return
          } else if (error.code == "auth/invalid-email") {
            Alert.alert('You entered and invalid email')
              return
        } else if (error.code == "auth/weak-password") {
            Alert.alert('Your password is too weak')
              return
        } else if (error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
            Alert.alert('Hey There!')
              return
        } else if (error.code == "auth/too-many-requests") {
            Alert.alert('Too many request. Try again in a minute.')
              return
        } 
          }
        },
        
        googleLogin: async () => {
          try {
            // Get the users ID token

             // Sign-in the user with the credential
             await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
            const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

            // Create a Google credential with the token
            const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

           
          } catch(error) {
            console.log({error});
          }
        },

        forgot: async (email) => {
          try {
            await firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
            Alert.alert("Success ✅", "A Password Recorvery Link has been sent to your mail.")
          }
          catch (e) {
           
        Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },

        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert(
            e.message  );
          }
        },

      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Lastly, below is the Login button.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => googleLogin()}
  style={[
    styles.signIn,
    {
      borderColor: '#191970',
      borderWidth: 1,
      marginTop: 15,
    },
  ]}>
  <LinearGradient colors={['#de4d41', '#de4d41']} style={styles.signIn}>
    <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="google" style={{ paddingRight: 20 }} />
    <Text
      style={[
        styles.textSign,
        {
          color: 'white',
        },
      ]}>
      Sign in with Google
    </Text>
  </LinearGradient>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

My major problem is the fact that I don't know exactly where the problem is coming from. Someone should please help...

Comment: Anybody? Please..

Comment: Can you make your example in stackblitz please?

Comment: The render looping typically occurs when you unconditionally update state... maybe in an `useEffect`, or some functional component's body, or a callback that triggers itself. I don't see anything obvious from the snippet. Are you sure there isn't at least a line number or something from React to indicate the file/function/etc the looping is occurring in?

Comment: I also implemented facebook login in the application and it works fine. I really don know why the google login is not working.